# how to search a mysql table using multiple inputs from a search field in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP/Mysql project where I have made a filter search for the data table.

But I realized it late that all the filters take only one input. I want to give many inputs in a single field using commas. So how can that be done?

SS of my filter, Code of the form and Sql query attached below.

[So when the search is done, the result is shown in the table on right side blank space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kON5t.jpg)

```
<?php
 $res = false;

 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $FirstName=$_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName=$_POST['LastName'];
    $Function=$_POST['Function'];
    $State=$_POST['State'];
    $Country =$_POST['Country'];
    $Website =$_POST['Website'];
    $sql=" SELECT * FROM hz WHERE FirstName like '%".$FirstName."%' AND LastName LIKE '%".$LastName."%' AND Function LIKE '%".$Function."%' AND State LIKE '%".$State."%' AND Country LIKE '%".$Country."%' AND Website LIKE '%".$Website."%'";
    $q=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
else{
  $res = true;
}
?>
```

**Form code:**

```
<form method="post" class="search">
    <table width="200">
    <td>
       <tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php if(isset($FirstName)) echo $FirstName;?>" /></tr>
       <tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="LastName" placeholder="Last name" value="<?php if(isset($LastName)) echo $LastName;?>" /></tr><BR>
<!--<tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="Company Standard Name" placeholder="Company Name" value="<?php if(isset($Company)) echo $Company;?>" /></tr><BR>
        <tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="Job Title" placeholder="Job Title" value="<?php if(isset($Job)) echo $Job;?>" /></tr><BR> -->
        <tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="Function" placeholder="Function" value="<?php if(isset($Function)) echo $Function;?>" /></tr><BR>
       <tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="State" placeholder="State" value="<?php if(isset($State)) echo $State;?>" /></tr><BR>
<!--       <tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="Zip Code" placeholder="Zipcode" value="<?php if(isset($Zip)) echo $Zip;?>" /></tr><BR> -->
       <tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="Country" placeholder="Country" value="<?php if(isset($Country)) echo $Country;?>" /></tr><BR>
       <tr><input class="form__input" type="search" name="Website" placeholder="Website" value="<?php if(isset($Website)) echo $Website;?>" /></tr><BR>    
       <tr><input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Search " class="button"/></tr>
    </td>
    </table>
</form>
```

Ps: `$con = mysqli_connect("host","user","password", "databasename");`

Comment: you have to use `foreach` to get multiple results

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I know i have to use foreach and explode. But how to implement it in above code, that's the problem...